# Error in LLVM STLExtras: expected unqualified-id before 'const' with GCC11

Tags: c++, class, gcc, constructor, llvm

I just upgraded my compiler to GCC 11.1.0 and having trouble trying to compile my program that uses LLVM.

The error that occurs is the following:

```
In file included from /usr/include/llvm/IR/DebugInfo.h:19,
                 from /home/<redacted>/src/sword/format/llvm.hpp:12,
                 from /home/<redacted>/src/main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h:1793:18: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
 1793 |   result_pair<R>(const result_pair<R> &Other)
      |                  ^~~~~
/usr/include/llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h:1793:18: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
 1793 |   result_pair<R>(const result_pair<R> &Other)
      |                 ~^~~~~
      |                  )
/usr/include/llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h:1843:22: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
 1843 |   enumerator_iter<R>(const enumerator_iter<R> &Other) : Result(Other.Result) {}
      |                      ^~~~~
/usr/include/llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h:1843:22: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
 1843 |   enumerator_iter<R>(const enumerator_iter<R> &Other) : Result(Other.Result) {}
      |                     ~^~~~~
      |                      )
```

I've looked at the source code but wasn't sure whether LLVM's code is ill-formed, or it's a GCC bug.

The error at line 1793 in STLExtra.h is related to the definition of a class:

```
template <typename R> struct result_pair {
  ...
  result_pair<R>(const result_pair<R> &Other)
      : Index(Other.Index), Iter(Other.Iter) {}
  ...
};
```

Usually, when I define a class with template parameters, I don't put the template parameters in the declaration of the constructor (i.e. `result_pair(...)`).
And indeed, my program compiled fine when I modified the constructors from `result_pair<R>(...)` to `result_pair(...)` (Did the same for `enumerator_iter`).

So, is LLVM's code wrong and GCC is correct? Or is this a GCC regression? My knowledge of the C++ standard is too limited to effectively Google to check whether this is a known bug or not... Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, I tried compiling my program using clang-11 but it fails to compile at all because the C++20 features are not there yet (specifically, it fails somewhere in  with templates). So, I couldn't narrow down the culprit that way.

P.S. Since it compiles just fine with the modification, I guess I'll just leave the header modified for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mention you're using C++20. This is indeed an error as of C++20: the use of simple-template-ids for constructors was deemed error-prone and redundant, and removed. See [[diff.cpp17.class]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp17.class#2).

As you mentioned, you can fix the error by using an injected class name instead:

```cpp
template <typename R>
struct result_pair {
  // ...
  result_pair(const result_pair &Other)
      : Index(Other.Index), Iter(Other.Iter) {}
  // ...
};
```

In particular, this prevents accidentally using the wrong template parameters in the constructor declaration, which obviously should not compile.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I guess I'll just have to modify LLVM until it gets fixed there. I assume that changing this won't give me an error when using pre C++20 standards. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: @funnypigrun yes, this modification has always been perfectly valid code.

Comment: Is there any way to relax this with c++20, may be some compiler flag? I have this in one of my dependencies...

Comment: @ViktorKhristenko Not that I'm aware of. That said, I checked and you might be able to avoid this by upgrading your dependency to LLVM 13, if possible, since taking a look at it this issue seems to have been fixed: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/release/13.x/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h#L1867

Answer (score 2):

Based on N. Shead's answer, here is a patch file that may be used to fix the error on LLVM 12.0.1:

```
--- /usr/include/llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h.orig  2021-10-21 10:41:36.706064183 -0400
+++ /usr/include/llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h   2021-10-21 10:41:59.442775225 -0400
@@ -1820,9 +1820,9 @@
   result_pair(std::size_t Index, IterOfRange<R> Iter)
       : Index(Index), Iter(Iter) {}
 
-  result_pair<R>(const result_pair<R> &Other)
+  result_pair(const result_pair &Other)
       : Index(Other.Index), Iter(Other.Iter) {}
-  result_pair<R> &operator=(const result_pair<R> &Other) {
+  result_pair &operator=(const result_pair &Other) {
     Index = Other.Index;
     Iter = Other.Iter;
     return *this;
@@ -1856,22 +1856,22 @@
   result_type &operator*() { return Result; }
   const result_type &operator*() const { return Result; }
 
-  enumerator_iter<R> &operator++() {
+  enumerator_iter &operator++() {
     assert(Result.Index != std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max());
     ++Result.Iter;
     ++Result.Index;
     return *this;
   }
 
-  bool operator==(const enumerator_iter<R> &RHS) const {
+  bool operator==(const enumerator_iter &RHS) const {
     // Don't compare indices here, only iterators.  It's possible for an end
     // iterator to have different indices depending on whether it was created
     // by calling std::end() versus incrementing a valid iterator.
     return Result.Iter == RHS.Result.Iter;
   }
 
-  enumerator_iter<R>(const enumerator_iter<R> &Other) : Result(Other.Result) {}
-  enumerator_iter<R> &operator=(const enumerator_iter<R> &Other) {
+  enumerator_iter(const enumerator_iter &Other) : Result(Other.Result) {}
+  enumerator_iter &operator=(const enumerator_iter &Other) {
     Result = Other.Result;
     return *this;
   }
```

Save the above to `~/STLExtras.h.patch` then apply the patch via:

```
$ sudo patch --backup /usr/include/llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h ~/STLExtras.h.patch
patching file /usr/include/llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h
```

The original will be saved to `/usr/include/llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h.orig` which you may either keep or delete.